# How do I use Power Automate and Microsoft Forms to create an automated new user access request process?

Tags: excel, power-automate, microsoft-forms

I currently manage SAP/Business Objects for my organization. I am attempting to automate a very manual, very cumbersome new user access request process into an automated process. My business objects platform has 16 user groups with 7 data owners/possible approvers, plus row level security that I need to know about to add. New users can need access to one or multiple folders/row level security permissions.

I created a Microsoft form that includes questions to get the required information. Questions 4-7 have multiple answers that can be selected.

1. What is the new user's name.
2. What is the new user's ID number
3. What is the new user's email address
4. Which Business Objects Folders does this user require access to? (Select all that apply)
5. Row level security question
6. Row level security question
7. Row level security question

Then, using power automate, I created a flow that would be triggered by this form being submitted; power automate then retrieves the data in the form and then adds the information to a row of data in Microsoft Excel. So, now I have an excel file that has all of my required data in it.

Here's where I'm stuck.

So, I have this excel file with the data I need in it. I have a list of emails for the data owners/approvers. If I were just using Excel, I'd just do an XLookup to match the folders with data owners. However, I'm not exactly sure how to do that. I tried writing a long conditional formula to consolidate the email addresses and then reference that in the Power Automate but couldn't get PA to recognize the output of the formulas. The more I read, the more I'm seeing that you can do this type of matching in PA without using excel at all but I'm having zero luck figuring out how.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.